# Canvas causes fuzzy images when resized

Tags: javascript, canvas

When drawing images on canvas, they look fine with `devicePixelRatio` equal to 2. With the ratio set to 1, the image is blurry. If i set the display zoom to 200% (devicePixelRatio = 2) it becomes clear again. It also only happens when resizing the image. If you skip the `fitToBox` call and make the canvas larger so you can see it, the image looks fine. Here is a demo https://jsfiddle.net/7oc1e3ja/

[image]

```
const getImageFromUrl = (context, url, coords) => {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    let img = new Image();
    img.src = url;

    img.onload = () => {
      fitToBox(img, coords);
      context.drawImage(img, coords.left, coords.top, img.width, img.height);
      resolve(img);
    }
  });
};

const fitToBox = (item, box) => {
    let ratio = Math.min(box.width / item.width, box.height / item.height);
    item.width *= ratio;
    item.height *= ratio;
};

const config = {
  imageUrl: 'https://i.imgur.com/y6viWyU.png',
  canvas: { width: 300, height: 300 },
};

let box = { ...config.canvas, top: 0, left: 0 },
    dpr = window.devicePixelRatio || 1,
    canvas = document.getElementById('c'),
    context = canvas.getContext('2d');

canvas.width = config.canvas.width * dpr;
canvas.height = config.canvas.height * dpr;
canvas.style.width = config.canvas.width + 'px';
canvas.style.height = config.canvas.height + 'px';
context.scale(dpr, dpr);

getImageFromUrl(context, config.imageUrl, box)
  .then(img => document.body.appendChild(img));
```

Comment: After 9 years of being an active member of this community you should know better our standards. Saying I have a problem with my code and only showing a screenshot of the result doesn't make a good question. The [mre] must be accessible from the post itself, not outsourced.  And for your problem, are you sure the `dpr` variable on your windows machine says `1`? IIRC there is a default ×1.25 zoom at the OS level.

Comment: Yes I'm sure the dpr says 1. It also looks bad at 1.25, 1.5, anything less than 2.

Comment: Just don't set `canvas.style.width` or height. Only use HTML width and height

Comment: `canvas` is just an image containing pixels. It's treated like an image when it is resized. If you want to keep the sharpness of the image, you've to change the size using `width` and `height` attribute to add pixels to the canvas, changing the CSS dimensions just stretches the pixels, and then redraw all the items in the canvas using an appropriate scale.

Comment: Changing the css width/height was purely for the screenshot. Doesn't have anything to do with the problem. Comment out the style changes and run the code. Same result.

Answer (score 2):

Just simply update your logic to calculate `dpr` value to:

`dpr = Math.max(window.devicePixelRatio || 2, 2),`

In that case you will have HiDPI canvas.

Comment: In that case may as well just set `dpr = 2` everywhere. I mean, it does work in this case but doesn't really fix the problem. More of a workaround. Can't believe more people aren't having this problem.

Answer (score 1):

After searching the w3 specification for hours, I found this can be caused by several things.

The output bitmap (what we see) of the context is not nessecary the same as the scratch bitmap. The canvas is allowed to store drawing actions instead on the scratch bitmap instead of do real rendering and updating (for performance reasons).

> The scratch bitmap, when it isn't the same bitmap as the output
> bitmap, is only directly observable if it is read, and therefore
> implementations can, instead of updating this bitmap, merely remember
> the sequence of drawing operations that have been applied to it until
> such time as the bitmap's actual data is needed (for example because
> of a call to commit(), drawImage(), or the createImageBitmap() factory
> method). In many cases, this will be more memory efficient.

That in addition that there is no strict specification how to write the alogithm for scaling images

> This specification does not define the precise algorithm to use when
> scaling an image down, or when scaling an image up

there also seems to be different implementations in different engines. I had a much smoother image with chrome and edge (both chrome engine) than in firefox.

Very confusing is that context.imageSmoothingEnabled had no effect in any engine (set on true and false).

All these points makes me think, that the scaling algorithm is handled different in every engine, ending in strange outputs.

The only way I see to accomplish the same experience on all devices is to write an own algrithm, load the image, scale it (and smoth it) with that algorithm and insert the new generated image.

But I think that's not worth the work.